# How to populate Radio button and Check box from database?

Tags: c#

I have Radio button on my page.I am saving the radio button value in database as 1 or 0 format. My question is when I want to populate the radio button how should i do?
Please can anyone help me

**EDIT:**

```
DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetHRInfo(userId); 
if((int)dt.Rows[0]["Active"] > 0)
{ 
  optIsActiveYes = 1; 
  ...
```

Can i assign a value like this?

Comment: `radiButton.IsChecked = intValueFromDb == 1;`

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? Asp.Net MVC? How do you get the data from your DB? We need a lot more info to be able to answer this question. If you're just starting out, google for a tutorial on ADO.Net or Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you already know how to store value to db I made assumption that you able to read it from DB as well, so:

Radio button will be checked when value is `1`, otherwise reseted, event you'are read wrong value like `2` or `-1`

EDIT: Update to a comment

```
DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetHRInfo(userId);
int activeValue;

// by default false
bool optIsActiveYes = false;
if (dt.Rows[0]["Active"] != null 
    && Int32.TryParse(dt.Rows[0]["Active"].ToString(), out activeValue))
{
    optIsActiveYes = activeValue == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok It was my mistake . . You can simply use
if(radioButton1Value == 1)
  radioButton1.Checked = true;
:)